# Vcard size limit when opening in contacts app

Tags: ios, contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to launch the ios contacts app from my app to open a vcard file with UIDocumentInteractionController. When I test with vcards with 500 contacts, I have no problems opening them with contacts app to import the contacts. When I try it with vcards with 3000 contacts (each contact with address, phones, emails, etc), the contacts app launches but it crashes before showing the contacts. I thought it was a problem with my app, but if I try to import the .vcf file from Dropbox app, I have the same problem. If I choose "Open in contacts app" from Safari, the contacts app crashes again.

However, if I try to import that vcard from Mail, I have no problems opening the save vcard.

I'm doing the tests with an iPhone4S with ios 7.0.4. If I try the same process with an iPhone5S with the same iOS version, I have no problems opening any vcard from my app.

Is there any limitation for contacts app in different devices to open vcards? Is there any way to debug contacts app to find the closing app reason?

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash with memory exception? If so it depends how you create your vcf file. I had similar problem with my iPhone 4S not able to open even 100 contacts with all data filled in. Problem with me was that I was collecting the vcf data into single string and then dumping it to file, which then was changed to dump as soon as you get something on string.